# Passing props to if statement on a Nested Map - React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm have a map nested with a map, and the nested map has an if statement. However it's not working because I need to reference a value from the outter mapped element. I'm not sure the proper syntax. I've tried many wrong things, lol.

How do I reference section.name from the outer element in the nested maps's if statement? I'm not getting any errors, it just doesn't work.

```
<Container>
     {this.state.sections.map(section => (
          <Accordion className="my-5" key={section.id} id={section.id}>
                 <Card key={section.id} id={section.id} name={section.name} 
                 style={{ background: this.state.color1, color: this.state.color2 }}>
                      <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey={section.id}>
                          Section {section.id}: {section.name}
                      </Accordion.Toggle>
                      <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={section.id}>
                          <Card.Body style={{ background: 'white', color: 'black' }}>
                                <ButtonGroup size="sm" className='buttons'>
                                      {this.state.policies.map(policy => {
                                           if(this.state.section === 'Culture'){
                                               return 
                                               <PolicyButton key={policy.id} id={policy.id} policy= 
                                                {policy.policy} onAddPolicy={this.handleAddPolicy} />
                                                    }
                                                })}
                                 </ButtonGroup>
                            </Card.Body>
                     </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
         </Accordion>
       ))}
</Container>
```

Comment: As fas as I know, you can directly access elements inside the inner map. there is nothing wrong with that. I just want to know what is not working out for you? You can try `console.log(section.name)` inside your inner map's if statement and see result.

Comment: If this is the IF condition you're referring to `if(this.state.section === 'Culture')` then you might need to change the condition to `if(section.name === 'Culture')` Or please post the code where you're referencing `section.name`